# Error when reading SQL table with Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sqlite

I have a web scraper that saves data to a sqlite database locally on my machine. At the beginning of the script, I have it load the database,

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('named_database.db')
alldata = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM table_in_named_database", conn)
```

which throws the following error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/emporerblk/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1404, in execute
    cur.execute(*args)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: table_in_named_database

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./path_to/this_script.py", line 127, in <module>
    main()
  File "./path_to/this_script.py", line 113, in main
alldata = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM table_in_named_database', conn)
  File "/Users/emporerblk/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 332, in read_sql_query
    parse_dates=parse_dates, chunksize=chunksize)
  File "/Users/emporerblk/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1439, in read_query
    cursor = self.execute(*args)
  File "/Users/emporerblk/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1416, in execute
    raise_with_traceback(ex)
  File "/Users/emporerblk/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 344, in raise_with_traceback
    raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
  File "/Users/emporerblk/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1404, in execute
    cur.execute(*args)
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM table_in_named_database': no such table: table_in_named_database
```

I know that the data exists because when I access it via the command line, it works.

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect("./path_to/named_database.db")
>>> conn
<sqlite3.Connection object at 0x112efab90>
>>> df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM table_in_named_database", conn)
>>> df.head(2)
                      column  \ ...
0   data  
1   data   
...
```

There's no apparent reason why the same line of code throws an error in a file but works perfectly. My questions are:

1) Does anyone know why this error is being thrown?

2) Is sqlite3 the problem? If so, what alternatives do you suggest?

Comment: Are the script and database files located in the same directory? `sqlite3.connect('named_database.db')` indicates a path relative to the invocation of the interpreter or script.